# Unable to install sacc chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a network with 2 orgs and 2 peers. I am trying to install the sample chaincode from the tutorial on one of the peers.

```
/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/sacc# CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7052 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc:0 ./sacc
2018-10-04 00:36:40.699 UTC [shim] SetupChaincodeLogging -> INFO 001 Chaincode log level not provided; defaulting to: INFO
2018-10-04 00:36:40.699 UTC [shim] SetupChaincodeLogging -> INFO 002 Chaincode (build level: ) starting up ...
2018-10-04 00:36:40.699 UTC [shim] userChaincodeStreamGetter -> ERRO 003 open : no such file or directory
error trying to read file content 
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim.userChaincodeStreamGetter
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go:89
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim.Start
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go:150
main.main
    /opt/gopath/src/chaincode/sacc/sacc.go:88
runtime.main
    /opt/go/src/runtime/proc.go:198
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
Error starting SimpleAsset chaincode: error trying to read file content : open : no such file or directoryroot@31b1a3b7d3da:/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/sacc#
```

Any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ERRO 003 open : no such file or directory error trying to read file content
```

your chaincode file dose not exist in the directory, please check that you have provided correct path of chaincode

Comment: Then what is `./sacc`?